# Diagram : alert management with E-mail and SMS

Tags: database, uml, analysis, diagram

I would like to use a diagram to do an analysis.
A plumber wishes to warn a customer of a plumbing maintenance via e-mail and sms!

For example "Dear Customer, you have a plumbing maintenance on 25 september".

I am stuck concerning e-mail and sms system in my analysis. 
How to integrate this in my modelization ?

Do you have an idea please?
[image]

Comment: Can that plumber survive with just one customer? What's your issue exactly?

Comment: Also, what are those `id`s? Still poking around in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901042/mcd-system-email-and-sms ?

Comment: @ Thomas Kilian, hi, how to add the e-mail and sms system in my analysis?

Comment: For what reason? Are they part of the system? If so, add them. If not, leave them out. What if the plumber gets a phone call? Or a personal talk?

Comment: @ Thomas Kilian: the system of email and SMS reminder to the customer his appointment in 2 days for example with the plumber. How to put this in an analysis?

Comment: I have no idea what your issue is. So I'm out.